# Can't access files on mounted shared folder from windows

Tags: mount, samba, shared-folders

I have access to a shared folder from windows to get some images for my webpage. I can mount it using the next command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //win-server/folder -o username=myuser,password=mypass /path_to_my_ubuntu_folder
```

But, when I go to the mounted directory, I can see the listing of the files, but I can't access them. Something like this:

[image: cant access this images]

What I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set ownership of your ubuntu folder to your unix user and group, and specify them when you mount it (uid and gid)

```
sudo mkdir -p /path_to_my_ubuntu_folder
sudo chown your_unix_user:your_unix_group /path_to_my_ubuntu_folder
sudo mount -t cifs //win-server/folder -o username=myuser,password=mypass,uid=your_unix_user,gid=your_unix_group /path_to_my_ubuntu_folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Permissions!

The user doesn't have access to the mounted folder. I just ran a *chmod* command to change folder permissions.

```
sudo chmod 777 images/*
```

Hope this can help somebody else.

Comment: Do we need to give permission before mounting? I have the same problem it says permission as -rwxrwxrwx but shows same error message when copying. Not only copying when opening in any editor too